# Podman-compose Error EACCES: permission denied, rmdir /usr/src/app/dist

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, nest, podman, podman-compose

I'm trying to orchestrate databases with an existing docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile that builds a NestJS app, using `"extends"` for the former in another docker-compose.yml file. I began with the simplest configuration that I could come up with, the following is the content of a docker compose file named "dev.docker-compose.yml":

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    user: node
    build:
        context: .
        target: deps
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
        - .local.env
    command: npm run start:local
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

And this is the stage (target) that I use, in Dockerfile:

```
# FROM node:18-alpine AS base # Also tried this
FROM node:18.16-bookworm-slim AS base

FROM base as deps

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json .npmrc ./

RUN npm ci --ignore-scripts

COPY --chown=node:node . .

USER node
```

Running `docker-compose -f dev.docker-compose.yml up -V --build --abort-on-container-exit`, yields:

```bash
  ❯ docker-compose -f dev.docker-compose.yml up -V --build --abort-on-container-exit
  Sending build context to Docker daemon  97.85kB
  [1/2] STEP 1/2: FROM node:18.16-bookworm-slim AS base
  [1/2] STEP 2/2: LABEL "com.docker.compose.image.builder"="classic"
  --> Using cache 3ee796e73ae3d85cfcc3f7e78d33929cf20caffcce45848c2742e2d2d775708f
  --> 3ee796e73ae3
  [2/2] STEP 1/8: FROM 3ee796e73ae3d85cfcc3f7e78d33929cf20caffcce45848c2742e2d2d775708f AS deps
  [2/2] STEP 2/8: RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install dumb-init
  --> Using cache 73a50b822c786935ba01f30090b4ec102a06168c4bf3676c65030735b4669886
  --> 73a50b822c78
  [2/2] STEP 3/8: WORKDIR /usr/src/app
  --> Using cache b59fb50c62f3d617b2d243d2db63686e28d4b79f768a4b1c8f38212a1aab8d8d
  --> b59fb50c62f3
  [2/2] STEP 4/8: COPY --chown=node:node package*.json .npmrc ./
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  --> Using cache 5b1db35130bf34490a19be3229844a3c077df07a9cc0eaef2f88db5f2a3fe7bc
  --> 5b1db35130bf
  [2/2] STEP 5/8: RUN npm ci --ignore-scripts
  --> Using cache 8a5603f691c52a5abc8e952c9b9306dc47fbcf65eab93e0f531b56b70ae57423
  --> 8a5603f691c5
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  --> c814c2b0f84e
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  --> 9cab6d5f03d2
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  --> 2c2529d9b5a5
  Successfully tagged docker.io/library/stix-pay-livelo-api:latest
  2c2529d9b5a5f97e09a18ff41e32ce12887a19d21d686271f262589b9103d4d4
  Successfully built 2c2529d9b5a5
  [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
  [+] Running 2/2
   ✔ Network stix-pay-livelo_default  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
   ✔ Container stix-pay-livelo-api-1  Created                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.1s 
  Attaching to stix-pay-livelo-api-1
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | 
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | > stix-pay-livelo@0.0.1 start:local
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | > npx cross-env NODE_ENV=local nest start --watch
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | 
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | 
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | 
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  |  Error  EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/src/app/dist'
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  |  
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1  | 
  stix-pay-livelo-api-1 exited with code 0
  Aborting on container exit...
  [+] Stopping 1/0
   ✔ Container stix-pay-livelo-api-1  Stopped                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
```

Note: all docker related commands are being emulated by [Podman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Podman) CLI.

What have I tried?

- use node user directive (in Dockerfile and Compose file);
- remove the entrypoint, I'm using dumb-init, installing through Dockerfile and using this:

```yaml
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/bin/dumb-init
      - --
```

- check image contents ownership:

```
  ❯ podman run -it 7389833718e6 sh
  /usr/src/app $ ls -la
  total 440
  drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node           284 Jun 24 19:52 .
  drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node             6 Jun 24 19:52 ..
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           176 Jun 23 23:19 .dockerignore
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           833 Jun 21 20:07 .npmrc
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           421 Jun 21 20:07 .swcrc
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           575 Jun 23 23:43 dev.docker-compose.yml
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           408 Jun 23 22:27 docker-compose.yml
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           171 Jun 21 20:07 nest-cli.json
  drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node         13888 Jun 24 19:52 node_modules
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node        407244 Jun 23 22:46 package-lock.json
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node          4844 Jun 23 22:46 package.json
  drwxr-xr-x    1 node     node           378 Jun 22 17:25 src
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           112 Jun 21 20:07 tsconfig.build.json
  -rw-r--r--    1 node     node           583 Jun 21 20:07 tsconfig.json
```

- trying copy with `chown` as the example Dockerfile;
- run podman service as root instead of user;

Running `npm run start:local` from within the image works as expected.

I've tried removing podman (and its tools: podman, podman-compose, podman-dnsname, podman-docker), installed [docker](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Docker) and docker-compose package, started its service as root, and, with the same Docker and compose files, I had success.

Maybe it's an incompatibility between Podman and Docker?

Versions:

```
  ❯ podman-compose -v 
  podman-compose version: 1.0.6
  ['podman', '--version', '']  
  using podman version: 4.5.1
  podman-compose version 1.0.6 
  podman --version 
  podman version 4.5.1
```

Comment: Despite your statement that, "all docker related commands are being emulated by Podman CLI", you appear to be running the *actual* `docker-compose` command, and it is communicating with the *actual* Docker daemon, unless you have in fact enabled the Podman REST API and are using that. Can you add some clarity here about your configuration?

Comment: But of course. You can see that I've linked to Arch Linux's Wiki Page about Podman. There, it's possible to find some packages that replace docker and by extend its daemon, entirely, for instance: podman-docker, and podman-composer. I'm using rootless Podman, so I need to override the env "DOCKER_HOST", to point to podman.sock; "DOCKER_BUILDKIT" is also disabled. Running any other podman command through, let's call it, docker "alias", yields: `Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /usr/etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.`. Everything from that Wiki page is setup to replace docker.

Comment: If you think that it's a valuable information that should be integrated into the post, I'll be happy to add it.